# can't connect to mysql database on android KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, mysql-connector-python, kivymd

here's my code, it works with no problems on my PC

```
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='sql12.freesqldatabase.com',
                                             database='database',
                                             user='username',
                                             password='password')
        sql_select_Query = "select * from movies"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
```

then i generate an `apk` file from `KivyMD` using `Buildozer`.

---

but i get this error when i test the `apk` file on my Android using `Logcat`, and the app closes without showing any messages

```
Error reading data from MySQL table 2003: can't connect to MySQL server on 
'sql12.freesqldatabase.com:3306' (7 No address associated with hostname)
```

i use `mysql-connector 'version 2.2.9` module.

---

i've also included INTERNET permission in my `buildozer.spec` file

`android.permissions = INTERNET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that my Phone had some permission troubles with the app, after giving internet permission inside my Phone the code worked perfectly.